# Large binaries add

Tags: c++

this is my first question, so I hope I will not break any of the given rules here on forum. I would like to ask you for help. Im really programming noob, but for homework I have to make a programm in C++ which will add 2 binary numbers. I was able to make it throught converting to a decimal and adding them. I did it bcs I already had some parts for it in my PC. My question is, everything is working fine unless I enter really big binary numbers. Changing data types make difference in results when our school program checks the code. Im not sure waht to change exactly. Thank you in advance. It looks like proble occure when decimal number with "e" has to be converted-

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;
    int main ()
    {
    int k = 0;
    int l = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    double number = 0;
    double numberb = 0;
    long dec;
    string input;
    string inputb;
    cout << "Enter two binary numbers:" << endl;

    cin >> input >> inputb;

    if(cin.fail ())
        {cout << "Wrong input." << endl;
        return 0;
        }





    for (i = input.length() - 1; i>=0; i-- )
    {
    if (input[i] != '1' && input[i] != '0')
    {
    cout << "Wrong input." << endl;
    return 0;
    }
    if (input[i] == '1')
    {
    number += pow((double)2,(int)j);
    }
    j++;
    }

    for (k = inputb.length() - 1; k>=0; k-- )
    {
    if (inputb[k] != '1' && inputb[k] != '0')
    {
    cout << "Wrong input." << endl;
    return 0;
    }
    if (inputb[k] == '1')
    {
    numberb += pow((double)2,(int)l);
    }
    l++;
    }

    dec = number+numberb;


    vector <double> bin_vector;
    long bin_num;






      while ( dec >= 1 )
        {
           bin_num = dec % 2;
           dec /= 2;
           bin_vector.push_back(bin_num);
        }

      cout << "Soucet: ";
      for ( int i = (double) bin_vector.size() - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
           cout << bin_vector[i] << "";

      cout <<  endl;
      return 0;


}
```

Comment: Considering the work you're putting in to this, it almost pains me to tell you that you don't have to convert to decimal for this to be done. And doing so, i.e solving the problem without having to convert to machine-decimal, will solve your big-number problem automatically. Secondly, you need to account for the possibility the two bit strings being *unequal* in length if you go down the road I'm suggesting.

Comment: yea, I understand that it could be easier to make it another way and right now Im considering this option. But I still have to add 0+0 option. My goal is to receive those points ina any cost :D ty for reply

Comment: I suggest that you define a function `string bin_sum(const string &a, const string &b)`. When you have done that, you can *test* that function by passing it known strings and checking the result.

Comment: This option, as you have noted, will hit an upper limit on the implemented representation of an integral. And using a larger integral just kicks the can further down the road, but its still there. You can do this. [See it live](http://ideone.com/qTZJ4X)

Comment: WhozCraig ...that's too much for me. I will try to study that code tonight. ty anyway. will be inspirative :)

Comment: and ty very much. I would buy you a beer if I could

Comment: If you pursue the `string` option, an advice: operate with the strings reversed, so your bit at 0 will be the 1, the bit at 1 the 2... the bit at `i` the `2^i`. You'll see that the algorithms will be easier.

Comment: @rodrigo or just use reverse iterators when walking the string, which std::string conveniently provides.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your teacher told you that `double` numbers are great for large numbers. They are, but they have a big disadvantage: They cannot represent large numbers exactly, since they (roughly speaking) only store the first few digits of the number, together with the position of the decimal point, like your pocket calculator shows (for example, `123456E13`).

So you should not use `double` numbers here at all, since you need *precise* results, no matter how large your numbers are. A better idea is process both strings simultaneously and store the result digit by digit in another string, called `result`.

By the way: Since `double` numbers can usually store 53 binary digits precisely, it's good that your tested the program with even more digits.